# $d^2f(A)(v_1,v_2)$ for $v_1,v_2 \in \mathbb{R}^4$ and $A \in \mathbb{R}^{2 \times2}$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a matrix: $A \in \mathbb{R}^{2 \times2}$.

I already showed that the function $$f: \mathbb{R}^{2 \times2} \cong \mathbb{R}^4 \to\mathbb{R} \\A \mapsto \det A$$

is continuously differentiable twice and that $df(A)=tr(A)$.

How can I compute $d^2f(A)(v_1,v_2)$ for $v_1,v_2 \in \mathbb{R}^4$ ?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

In order to answer your question we need to specify the isomorphism ${\mathbb R}^{2\times2}\cong{\mathbb R}^4$. For simplicity I write your matrices as
$$X=\left[\matrix{X_1&X_2\cr X_3&X_4\cr}\right]\ .$$
The determinant function is then given by
$$f(X):=X_1X_4-X_2X_3\ .$$
For a given and fixed matrix $A$ we then obtain
$$df(A)(v)=\sum_{k=1}^4{\partial f\over\partial X_k}(A)\, v_k=A_4v_1-A_3v_2-A_2v_3+A_1v_4\ ,$$
which you can also write as matrix product
$$df(A)(v)=\nabla f(A).v\ ,$$
whereby $\nabla f(A)$ is considered as a row vector. Note that the trace of $A$ plays no rôle here.

The second derivative of $f$ at $A$ is a quadratic form in the variables $v_k$, and is given by
$$d^2f(A)(v)=\sum_{i,\, k=1}^4{\partial^2f\over\partial X_i\partial X_k}(A)\> v_i\,v_k\ .$$
In the case at hand the Hessian  has the following simple form, which is independent of $A$:
$$\left[{\partial^2f\over\partial X_i\partial X_k}(A)\right]_{i,\,k}=\left[\matrix{0&0&0&1\cr 0&0&-1&0\cr  0&-1&0&0\cr  1&0&0&0\cr}\right]=:H\ . $$
We then can write
$$d^2f(A)(v)=v^\top H\, v\ .$$